# Image getting cut out

Tags: css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/arp8x/

As you can see the image gets cut out. I cannot make it display entirely without taking the markers functionality away.

```
<div id="wrapper-AddSensors_img">
   <img id="AddSensors_img" src="http://3011victor.com/downloads/floorplan.gif" />
</div>


#wrapper-AddSensors_img {
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper-AddSensors_img img, #wrapper .marker {
    position: absolute;
}
#wrapper-AddSensors_img img {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#wrapper-AddSensors_img .marker {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Your design is so ridiculous, it has `<table>` and then all things are put in single row `<tr>` in single table data `<td>`.

Comment: I copied it from the plugin demo page. It's not in my original page.
Thanks for the comment though, really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NkCPA/1/

I have added these lines to the end of your stylesheet:

```
#wrapper-AddSensors_img > img:first-child {
    position: relative;
}

.swMain .stepContainer div.content {
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

The relative positioning allows the #wrapper and .content divs to get the height of the img. Setting the .content height to auto lets the browser calculate the correct height for large images, so you can use this code with other sized images too.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually a better solution since it's dynamic

Answer (score 3):

This is your code

```
<div class="stepContainer" style="height: 450px;"><div id="step-1" class="content" style="display: block;">
                     <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 1 Content</h2>
 <span class="marker black" style="display:none"></span>

                    <div id="wrapper-AddSensors_img">
                        <img id="AddSensors_img" src="http://3011victor.com/downloads/floorplan.gif">
                    </div>
                </div><div id="step-2" class="content" style="display: none;">
                     <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2>  
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div><div id="step-3" class="content" style="display: none;">
                     <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3 Content</h2>  
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div><div id="step-4" class="content" style="display: none;">
                     <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 4 Content</h2>  
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div></div>


<div class="stepContainer" style="height: 450px;"><div id="step-1" class="content" style="display: block;">
```

please see this line above and you will see the `style="height:450px"` has been increased.

and also increase the

```
.swMain .stepContainer div.content {
display: block;
position: absolute;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
font: normal 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #5A5655;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
height: 435px;  /* see it */
text-align: left;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 88;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
width: 968px;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was complete crap before I edited to make it somewhat better. Put more than 20 seconds into a post to at least make it _readable_

Answer (score 2):

Remove the overflow property from below class

```
.swMain .stepContainer
{
    overflow:hidden; //remove this
}
```

And then adjust your css accordingly by giving height and margin

Comment: I removed it, but can't seem to change the height. Where could I increase it?

Comment: in ".swMain .stepContainer div.content" class increase height property value. and also in ".swMain div.actionBar" class set increase margin property value.